# I am using Vue.js 2.0 and I am trying to emit an event from `child component`

Tags: javascript, vue.js, emit

I am using Vue.js 2.0 and I am trying to emit an event from `child component` to `parent component` but it's not working.

You can see my code below:

**child component:**

```
<template>
  <button @click="confirmSendMessage">Send</button>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      confirmSendMessage () {
        this.$emit('confirmed')
      }
    }
</script>
```

**parent component:**

```
<template>
    <ConfirmMessage/>
</template>

<script>
    import ConfirmMessage from './ConfirmMessage'
    export default {
        events: {
           confirmed() {
              console.log('confirmed')
           }
        },
        components: {
            ConfirmMessage
        }
   }
</script>
```

When I click on the button, nothing appears to me on the Chrome console.
I don't know why. Can anybody help me? I am new on Vue JS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You missed to listen the emitted event. Use [v-on](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Listening-to-Events) to listen to the event:

```
<!--                               vv -> call method -->
<ConfirmMessage v-on:confirmed="confirmed" />
<!--                  ^^ -> emitted event -->
```

Comment: Now I got this on console: `Property or method "confirmed" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.` :S

Answer (score 3):

You have to listen the events, if you look the [Emit Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit), it expects as first argument the name of the event as string, an then the values (if you have) you want to pass to the listener.

so it will be:

```
<confirm-message :nameOfEvent="functionToExecuteWhenTheEventIsEmitted" />
```

the method will be:

```
functionToExecuteWhenTeEventIsEmitted(someValue) { //do whatever with someValue}
```

and on the child:

```
this.$emit('nameOfEvent', someValue)
```

**In your case**

You aren't passing values so `this.$emit('confirmed')` and `<ConfirmMessage :confirmed="confirmed">` it  will be enought

Comment: passing the value is not necessary.

Comment: it was a full example, you can avoid it, then just use the name of the event

Comment: As of Vue 2, you should use kebab-case for the events name, otherwise it won't work, as explained in the [docs](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html)